# How long of an outage for ISSU Nexus Upgrade?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os, cisco-nexus-7k, nx-os

I am in the progress of doing ISSU upgrades on some nexus 7710 chassis' with dual supervisor modules. I set a ping test that to traverse across the switch shortly before the upgrade and experienced about 15-20 seconds of lost pings. Is this test scenario a good one and does this amount of downtime seem acceptable? Is cisco's marketing on this feature just bs? I see the same behavior for a supervisor switchover as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The interfaces of the 7K we were upgrading didn't have the 'no ip redirects' command on. This caused a drop in BFD between the neighboring router we were testing from and also dropped our EIGRP neighborship. This list has similar information: https://lists.gt.net/cisco/nsp/141379

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Will do, stack exchange has set a limit that I can't accept it for another 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The best tip I can give for anything involving ISSU on 7K's is to read- and re-read- the release notes.  There are very specific versions that are supported as origin/destination and there are also some features that are going to work better with ISSU than others.  The other caveat to consider is that in some instances there may be requirements for firmware or EPLD upgrades that could create a brief outage (again - usually mentioned in release notes).

In general I can tell you that the ISSU process *can* be truly hitless but that you need to stick within the limits of what QA has specifically validated.

Comment: I was able to check the release notes and the path we are using is supported. I'm not certain this is an ISSU issue but rather the failing over of the HA pair of supervisors.

Comment: What version to what version?  All F3 LC's or do you have some F2e or M3's in the mix?  Also - which features are in use?  It may be that there are one or two specific things causing the issue.  There tend to be improvements to address specific features in ISSU - so a recently implemented set like VXLAN might cause an issue where older features like VPC or ASM multicast might not.

Comment: 7.2.1.D1.1 to 7.3.1.D1.1. Just the dual sup and 2 F3 cards. Features are -feature privilege
feature scp-server
feature sftp-server
feature tacacs+
feature bgp
feature eigrp
feature udld
feature interface-vlan
feature netflow
feature hsrp
feature lacp
feature vpc
feature lldp
feature bfd
feature sla sender
feature sla responder